# Как у знать пол (женский) пользователя в instagram.com?

Tags: html, css, facebook, instagram, соцсети

Как определить пол на instagram.com у пользователя интересует женский

в facebook можно это так сделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

При регистрации в социальной сети Instagram можно указать свой пол. Но поле это не является обязательным, и доступно лишь при переходе в редактирование профиля. Вызвано это многими причинами, но как есть – уже не исправить. Соответственно, посмотреть пол определённого профиля нельзя как и в приложении, так и в веб-версии и различных сервисах.

Можно попробовать что-то вроде социальной инженерии и попытаться определить пол фотографиям, по описаниям к постам, ведь мужские и женские описания частенько очень отличаются по структуре.